# I am using ClosedXML library to export excel in my asp.net core mvc project.i want to sort name column by ascending.if anybody has any idea about that

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, closedxml

I am using the ClosedXML library to export data into Excel from my ASP.NET Core MVC project. I want to sort `name` column in ascending order. If anybody has any idea about that, please let me know.

[Link to ClosedXML Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUy2f.png)

My code:

```
public dynamic Export()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Grid");
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] {
             new DataColumn("Name"),
             new DataColumn("Skills"),
             new DataColumn("TotalStudents"),
             new DataColumn("Salary"),
             new DataColumn("AddedOn")
        });

        var teachers = from Teacher in this.schoolContext.Teacher.Take(200)
                       select Teacher;

        foreach (var teacher in teachers)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(teacher.Name, teacher.Skills, 
                        teacher.TotalStudents, teacher.Salary, teacher.AddedOn);
        }
            
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(stream);
                return (stream.ToArray()) ;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e.InnerException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you change your query syntax as below

```
var teachers =  from Teacher in this.schoolContext.Teacher.Take(200)
                orderby Teacher.Name
                select Teacher;
```